# nginx proxy all request through authentication service

Tags: nginx, proxy

Consider a dockerized environment containing the following containers:

1. Backend API
2. Front-end REACT App served using pushstate-server
3. Authentication Service
4. Nginx Container

My nginx.conf contains the following:

```
server {
    listen 8080;        

    location / {
        auth_request /auth;
        proxy_pass http://frontend:5000;
    }       

    location = /auth {
        proxy_pass http://auth:6000;
    }

    error_page 403 = @error403;
    location @error403 {
        rewrite ^ /login$1;
        proxy_pass http://frontend:5000;
    }
}
```

When the `auth_request /auth;` line is commented out, everything works just fine and all frontend pages can be accessed.

As soon as I introduce the `auth_request` I can see the authentication service return a 403 however, it does not look like Nginx proxies to the login page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

Firstly, the authorization header is not forwarded to the authentication service. This was fixed with

```
location = /auth {
    proxy_pass http://auth:6000;
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
}
```

Secondly, when a request is made to the frontend, nginx tries to authenticate with the `auth` container. As I am not authenticated, this fails and returns a 403. The nginx server then proxies to the login page on the REACT container, however, there are further request behind the scenes to retrieve `css` and `js` resources from the same container, for which the nginx gateway tries to authenticate. Again, as I am not authenticated retrieving these resources fails, so the page does not render.

A dirty solution was to add:

```
location /static/js/main.1e2389bc.js {
    proxy_pass http://web:5000;
}

location /static/css/main.aa587518.css {
    proxy_pass http://web:5000;
}
```

This retrieves the necessary files to render the login page with trying to authenticate. This is a bad solution as there may be other resources (favicon, other media etc.) so more blocks would need to be added. I am sure there is a simple solution using regex to sort this out in a simple way.

However, I ended up with a cleaner solution. Authenticate on requests to the backend API. This ensured that no sensitive information was displayed on the frontend without being authenticated and removed the hassle of hacking a solution to render the login page.